# VB Script XML selectNodes loses context when using namespace agnostic query

Tags: xml, xpath, vbscript, namespaces

When querying an XML file with xpath in VB script the "context" of a selected node set is lost when using namespace agnostic queries: **(Look in the 'For...Next' below for the specific example)**

```vb
 Dim Results :Set Results = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
 Results.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
 Results.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:results='http://example.domain.org/XMLSchema/results-example-3'
 dim defEXdef
 set defEXdef = Results.selectNodes("//*[local-name()='definition']")
 dim def

 'PROBLEM OCCURS IN THIS FOR...NEXT loop
 For Each def in defEXdef
      'HERE: The commented line below works successfully to load the "extended_definitions" elements out from the current "def"
      'dim extended_definitions : set extend_definitions = def.getElementsByTagName("results:extended_definitions")

      'HERE: The line below returns all extended_definitions nodes and ignores the parent's context - as though "def" is now the whole document
      dim extended_definitions : set extended_definitions = def.selectNodes("//*[local-name()='extended_definitions']")
      dim edef
           For Each edef in extended_definitions
                ExDefDict.add edef.text
           Next
 Next
```

It seems that the issue can be resolved by removing the "//" from the `selectNodes` statement, but why is this? How does the "def' item in the code contain more information than its original query selected?

I do not have sample XML as this is a rather contrived example (the original document is too sensitive to post). I can attempt to generate sample XML if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your path with `//` then it searches down from the document node, use `def.selectNodes(".//*[local-name()='extended_definitions']")` to search descendants of the `def` node and not of the document node.

Comment: So despite the fact that "def" should be the selected node from the beginning of the code, it still does not have context? I guess I'm still too new to all this!

Comment: It has context but you can navigate anywhere, up to the root node `/`, to a child `foo`, to a silbling `preceding-sibling::foo`, to a descendant `descendant::foo`. You want descendants (at least what is what the `getElementsByTagName` gives you), with XPath you get them with `descendant::foo` or `.//foo` which is short for `./descendant-or-self::node()/foo`.

Comment: Martin, thank you! I should have known better! I guess the computer always gives you exactly what you ask for :P Thank you for the help!